# ioctl error during btrfs send

Tags: linux, backup, btrfs

I am getting this error when I try to back up my @home btrfs subvolume from my laptop running Arch Linux to my external drive. This seems like a straightforward error, but **the strange thing is that I can back up two other subvolumes without seeing any errors.** My backup drive is a 1TB Western Digital internal SATA drive that I have connected using a Sabrent hard drive power adapter and an eSATA to SATA cable. The message below seems to only apply when I try to back up @home.

```
$ btrfs send hd/\@home-2016-02-04/ | btrfs receive bu
At subvol hd/@home-2016-02-04/
At subvol @home-2016-02-04
ERROR: send ioctl failed with -5: Input/output error
ERROR: unexpected EOF in stream.
$
```

The `hd` and `bu` directories are mounted to to top level of my laptop's internal drive and my backup drive, respectively. Also, I have run `btrfs scrub start hd/\@home` and it found one "uncorrectable error."

I have several questions:

- Does anyone know what this error means?
- What causes this error?
- How do I fix this problem?

Here is the `dmesg` output of starting at the beginning of an attempt to send the subvolume.

```
[   32.209649] BTRFS error (device sda3): could not find root 8
[   32.210105] BTRFS error (device sda3): could not find root 8
[   32.222637] BTRFS error (device sda3): could not find root 8
[   32.223030] BTRFS error (device sda3): could not find root 8
[   34.527358] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.527361] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.527366] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.506005] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[   46.506009] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[   46.506010] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[   46.506012] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[   46.506013] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
[   46.581646] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x11: 0xffd0
[   46.607577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp12s0: link is not ready
[   46.666191] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   46.877179] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   47.887409] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x11: 0xffd1
[ 1402.840138] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlp12s0 Scan_results error (-22)
[ 1773.586469] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x11: 0xffd0
[ 1927.838434] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x11: 0xffd1
[ 2225.726153] ata5: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0800 action 0xe frozen
[ 2225.726165] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2225.726173] ata5: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[ 2225.726185] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2227.410095] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 2227.423783] ata5.00: ATA-9: WDC WD10EZEX-22BN5A0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
[ 2227.423790] ata5.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[ 2227.425307] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2227.425322] ata5: EH complete
[ 2227.425564] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EZEX-22B 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 2227.425943] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[ 2227.425948] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 2227.426024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2227.426029] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[ 2227.426063] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 2227.490362]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2227.490756] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2227.761449] BTRFS: device fsid 9e494ae3-80dc-463f-8470-95de63236458 devid 1 transid 1407 /dev/sdb1
[ 2274.190804] BTRFS info (device sdb1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2274.190807] BTRFS: has skinny extents
[ 2280.668547] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2280.668554] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2280.668558] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2280.668563] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2284.779862] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 2284.795950] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2284.795958] ata5: EH complete
[ 2291.074138] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2291.074151] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2291.074158] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2291.074167] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2295.323391] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 2295.331830] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2295.331838] ata5: EH complete
[ 2302.760251] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2302.760264] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2302.760271] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2302.760282] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2303.479863] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 2303.821847] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2304.140154] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 2304.140180] ata5: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 2304.977828] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2309.146521] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2309.155122] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2309.155135] ata5: EH complete
[ 2309.921108] ata5.00: limiting speed to UDMA/100:PIO4
[ 2309.921122] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2309.921129] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2309.921136] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2309.921146] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2311.510072] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2312.664288] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2312.983216] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2313.023080] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2317.613196] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2317.624127] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2317.624134] ata5: EH complete
[ 2319.963041] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2319.963046] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2319.963049] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2319.963053] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2324.106731] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2324.120928] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2324.120936] ata5: EH complete
[ 2327.476226] ata5.00: limiting speed to UDMA/33:PIO4
[ 2327.476239] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2327.476247] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2327.476253] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2327.476263] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2331.616572] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2331.631075] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 2331.631088] ata5: EH complete
[ 2345.214552] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4010000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2345.214564] ata5: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2345.214571] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg DevExch }
[ 2345.214581] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2345.933337] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2350.933463] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2351.253332] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2356.253320] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2356.573402] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2356.573415] ata5.00: disabled
[ 2356.573430] ata5: EH complete
[ 2356.573482] ata5.00: detaching (SCSI 4:0:0:0)
[ 2356.575939] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 2356.575961] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[ 2356.680201] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 1, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680355] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 2, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680367] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.680370] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 29360128, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.680413] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 3, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680453] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 4, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680514] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 5, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680531] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 6, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680544] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 7, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680559] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 8, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680569] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.680572] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 60158902272, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.680611] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 9, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680648] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 10, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2356.680746] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.680749] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 69285707776, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.680932] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.680935] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 71970062336, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.681123] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.681126] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 84318093312, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.681317] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.681319] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 104182317056, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.681514] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.681516] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 111698509824, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.681728] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.681731] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 119751573504, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.681923] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.681925] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 143910764544, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.682127] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.682129] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 153574440960, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.682310] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.682313] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 158406279168, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.682497] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.682499] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 178807373824, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.682663] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.682666] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 183639212032, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.682867] BTRFS error (device sdb1): error reading free space cache
[ 2356.682870] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): failed to load free space cache for block group 199745339392, rebuilding it now
[ 2356.683039] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 2356.683079] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1525 at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:7451 find_free_extent+0xdf6/0xe60 [btrfs]()
[ 2356.683081] BTRFS: Transaction aborted (error -5)
[ 2356.683083] Modules linked in: bnep ext4 mbcache jbd2 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btusb videobuf2_core btrtl v4l2_common btbcm btintel bluetooth crc16 videodev hid_generic media joydev dell_rbtn dell_wmi iTCO_wdt dell_laptop mousedev snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic gpio_ich iTCO_vendor_support sparse_keymap coretemp ppdev dcdbas input_leds kvm_intel evdev psmouse kvm snd_hda_intel dell_smm_hwmon mac_hid snd_hda_codec irqbypass serio_raw pcspkr snd_hda_core i2c_i801 snd_hwdep wl(PO) snd_pcm e1000e lpc_ich nvidia(PO) snd_timer cfg80211 snd ptp drm parport_pc wmi rfkill intel_agp pps_core soundcore parport button battery thermal acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio intel_gtt acpi_cpufreq tpm_tis tpm video ac processor shpchp sch_fq_codel pci_stub vboxpci(O) vboxdrv(O)
[ 2356.683201]  ip_tables x_tables crc32c_generic btrfs xor raid6_pq sr_mod cdrom sd_mod usbhid hid atkbd libps2 ahci libahci firewire_ohci firewire_core crc_itu_t sdhci_pci sdhci led_class mmc_core libata scsi_mod ehci_pci uhci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common i8042 serio
[ 2356.683227] CPU: 0 PID: 1525 Comm: umount Tainted: P           O    4.4.1-2-ARCH #1
[ 2356.683229] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision M2400                 /0HT029, BIOS A23 08/19/2010
[ 2356.683231]  0000000000000000 0000000014251078 ffff880006c23930 ffffffff812c7f39
[ 2356.683234]  ffff880006c23978 ffff880006c23968 ffffffff810765b2 0000000000000000
[ 2356.683236]  0000000000000001 ffff8800da9985a0 00000000fffffffb ffff88000b908bf8
[ 2356.683239] Call Trace:
[ 2356.683246]  [<ffffffff812c7f39>] dump_stack+0x4b/0x72
[ 2356.683251]  [<ffffffff810765b2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[ 2356.683253]  [<ffffffff8107664c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[ 2356.683265]  [<ffffffffa026c33f>] ? __btrfs_alloc_chunk+0x70f/0x910 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683273]  [<ffffffffa0231c46>] find_free_extent+0xdf6/0xe60 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683281]  [<ffffffffa0231d3b>] btrfs_reserve_extent+0x8b/0x170 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683289]  [<ffffffffa0231f29>] btrfs_alloc_tree_block+0x109/0x500 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683297]  [<ffffffffa0219621>] __btrfs_cow_block+0x141/0x590 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683304]  [<ffffffffa0219c02>] btrfs_cow_block+0x112/0x1d0 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683310]  [<ffffffffa02bc364>] commit_cowonly_roots+0x5b/0x2c2 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683318]  [<ffffffffa022eb4b>] ? btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x1fb/0x290 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683329]  [<ffffffffa02ab133>] ? btrfs_qgroup_account_extents+0x83/0x130 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683338]  [<ffffffffa0243d02>] btrfs_commit_transaction+0x512/0xb20 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683348]  [<ffffffffa02443ae>] ? start_transaction+0x9e/0x4c0 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683357]  [<ffffffffa023d79f>] btrfs_commit_super+0x8f/0xa0 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683366]  [<ffffffffa023f239>] close_ctree+0x2a9/0x350 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683373]  [<ffffffffa0212fe9>] btrfs_put_super+0x19/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683376]  [<ffffffff811e103a>] generic_shutdown_super+0x6a/0xf0
[ 2356.683377]  [<ffffffff811e1352>] kill_anon_super+0x12/0x20
[ 2356.683384]  [<ffffffffa02128e8>] btrfs_kill_super+0x18/0x120 [btrfs]
[ 2356.683386]  [<ffffffff811e14f3>] deactivate_locked_super+0x43/0x70
[ 2356.683388]  [<ffffffff811e210c>] deactivate_super+0x5c/0x60
[ 2356.683391]  [<ffffffff811fd4ef>] cleanup_mnt+0x3f/0x90
[ 2356.683394]  [<ffffffff811fd582>] __cleanup_mnt+0x12/0x20
[ 2356.683396]  [<ffffffff810922e3>] task_work_run+0x73/0x90
[ 2356.683399]  [<ffffffff8100369a>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0xba/0xc0
[ 2356.683401]  [<ffffffff81003b9e>] syscall_return_slowpath+0x4e/0x60
[ 2356.683404]  [<ffffffff81591c8c>] int_ret_from_sys_call+0x25/0x8f
[ 2356.683405] ---[ end trace 6020b75ba7c696b8 ]---
[ 2356.683408] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): find_free_extent:7451: Aborting unused transaction(IO failure).
[ 2356.683412] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
[ 2356.683414] BTRFS warning (device sdb1): cleanup_transaction:1746: Aborting unused transaction(IO failure).
[ 2356.683415] BTRFS info (device sdb1): delayed_refs has NO entry
[ 2356.683419] BTRFS error (device sdb1): commit super ret -5
[ 2362.946500] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[ 2362.946508] ata5: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 2362.946511] ata5: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[ 2362.946518] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 2367.733473] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 2367.743748] ata5.00: ATA-9: WDC WD10EZEX-22BN5A0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
[ 2367.743754] ata5.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[ 2367.744513] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2367.744526] ata5: EH complete
[ 2367.748255] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EZEX-22B 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 2367.748962] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[ 2367.748972] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 2367.749113] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2367.749123] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[ 2367.749188] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 2367.810270]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2367.810667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2383.375826] BTRFS info (device sdb1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2383.375830] BTRFS: has skinny extents
[ 2897.986685] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x71000001 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2897.986692] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 2897.986696] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2897.986704] ata1.00: cmd 60/38:e0:68:52:ec/00:00:05:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq 28672 in
                        res 41/40:38:98:52:ec/00:00:05:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2897.986707] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2897.986710] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2898.210840] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2898.210877] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 2898.210883] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] [descriptor] 
[ 2898.210887] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4 
[ 2898.210892] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 05 ec 52 68 00 00 38 00
[ 2898.210896] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 99373720
[ 2898.210900] btrfs_dev_stat_print_on_error: 102 callbacks suppressed
[ 2898.210905] BTRFS error (device sda3): bdev /dev/sda3 errs: wr 0, rd 19, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2898.210931] ata1: EH complete
[ 2902.959951] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x400000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2902.959958] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 2902.959962] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2902.959970] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:b0:98:52:ec/00:00:05:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq 4096 in
                        res 41/40:08:98:52:ec/00:00:05:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2902.959973] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2902.959976] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2903.082344] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2903.082362] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 2903.082366] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] [descriptor] 
[ 2903.082368] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4 
[ 2903.082371] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 05 ec 52 98 00 00 08 00
[ 2903.082373] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 99373720
[ 2903.082376] BTRFS error (device sda3): bdev /dev/sda3 errs: wr 0, rd 20, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[ 2903.082389] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg` for disk error messages?

Comment: @grawity, I have added some `dmesg` output.

Comment: I believe that pretty much translates to "your disk is dead"...

Comment: You mean my laptop's internal disk? I got WD drive in December, but my internal drive is fairly old. As noted earlier, the strange thing is that the other subvolumes I back up (everything not in my home folder) give me no errors at all.

Comment: That's not unusual at all. HDDs don't usually fail completely – you start with just a few bad sectors and they spread over time. (You don't even notice the first few because the drive has spare areas to reallocate them, unless you habitually check SMART counters.)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's time for me to get an SSD; although I will probably end up getting a new computer within the next year, so maybe this one will survive long enough. Do you know how to determine where the bad files are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I got it working. I reverted to an older version of my `@home` subvolume and copied back some of the changes that had occurred since the last backup. When I tried to copy my Firefox profile, it was not completely transferred, so I just updated the older version.